# how to remove particular string should they exists, for all columns

Tags: r, multiple-columns, data-cleaning

In R programming, for all column names, I would like to remove the string "Cs." if it exists. X.x doesn't contain "Cs." in this case. How do I go about?

---

```
Cs.Month | X.x | Cs.ID | Cs.Discharge
--------------------------------------
Jan 2017 | 1   | 8931  | A
--------------------------------------
Jul 2017 | 7   | 8931  | B
--------------------------------------
```

I would like the dataframe to become like this:

---

```
Month    | X.x | ID    | Discharge
--------------------------------------
Jan 2017 | 1   | 8931  | A
--------------------------------------
Jul 2017 | 7   | 8931  | B
--------------------------------------
```

Are there methods to do in tidyverse, and base R?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use regex:

```
colnames(df) <- gsub("Cs\\.", "", colnames(df))
```